# Jenkins Dynamic Combination Matrix

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I've been using the option **Restrict matrix execution to a subset** from the  **Parameterized Trigger Plugin** to pass on a combination filter to a rather large Matrix Project where all test execution is made. As the number of tests grow, so does the combination filter (which is dynamically built up) and I seemed to hit the cap. The following job gets this error message:

`FATAL: Invalid method Code length 69871 in class file Script1
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Invalid method Code length 69871 in class file Script1`

After reading about this problem, it seems to be a JVM constraint after reading the JVM [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.9.1)

> The value of the code_length item must be less than 65536.

I get the impression that this is not something I can (or even should) tinker with in Jenkins.

My second idea was to go around this problem was to create the combination filter and then pass it as String parameter to the following Matrix Project, then use the **Combination Filter** option and expand the variable to achieve the same result.

Unfortunately I get this exception when trying to save my Matrix Project with a String parameter as combination filter

`javax.servlet.ServletException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: $COMBINATION_FILTER for class: groovy.lang.Binding`

I guess this is because the variable needs to be available in the configuration when saving but I want to inject it when starting the Matrix Project.

I am running out of ideas to solve this problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [Matrix Groovy Execution Strategy](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Groovy+Execution+Strategy+Plugin) which is like a super combination filter

If I can quote myself

> A plugin to decide the execution order and valid combinations of
>   matrix projects.
>
> This uses a user defined groovy script to arrange the order which will
>   then be executed

Disclaimer: I built this plugin

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. I've started trying out the plugin but i cant figure out how to use it. The Wiki is very thin, and only one example is made there.

I need to dynamically create the combination filter in a pre-job. And then only use it as input in Matrix Groovy Execution Strategy. I'm having a hard time figuring out the syntax for the pre-job.